# Docker Traefik can't resolve DNS (Fails reaching server and obtaining certificates)

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik

Googling the following issue shows that this hasn't been posted the first time, however, none of them really give an answer.

When starting Traefik (v2.2.1 aka. latest) as a container in Docker, no matter what I try, I keep getting following error, for ALL the domains configured:

```
time="2020-05-24T15:48:57Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"<my domain>\": cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp: lookup acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:44687->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout" routerName=traefik@docker rule="Host(`<my domain>`)" providerName=le.acme
```

---

Checking https://letsencrypt.status.io/ it doesn't seem to be a problem of Let's Encrypt's servers

[image]
[image]

---

I have tried with two different OSs on the server Debian 10, Ubuntu Server 18.04 and 20.04. While installing the OS, I always follow my guide I created for myself here: https://gist.github.com/D3strukt0r/5aaba1a021d16b31fa19adf6eb26a102

Yes, I do as little as possible in the system and as much as possible with the containers.

---

Following is my `docker-compose.yml` for Traefik

```yaml
version: "2"

# Manage domain access to services
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefik_proxy
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${ACME_EMAIL}
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare
      # - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1:53,8.8.8.8:53
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      #- ./acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./acme_testing.json:/acme.json
    environment:
      CF_API_EMAIL: ${CF_API_EMAIL}
      CF_API_KEY: ${CF_API_KEY}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.rule=Host(`<my domain>`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik0.middlewares=to_https

      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`<my domain>`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik_auth
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal

      # Declaring the user list
      #
      # Note: all dollar signs in the hash need to be doubled for escaping.
      # To create user:password pair, it's possible to use this command:
      # echo $(htpasswd -nb user password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
      - traefik.http.middlewares.traefik_auth.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_USERS}

      # Standard middleware for other containers to use
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https_perm.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.to_https_perm.redirectscheme.permanent=true

networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
```

The folder structure in there:

```
root@server:/opt/traefik# ls -Al
total 8
-rw------- 1 root root      0 May 24 00:37 acme.json
-rw------- 1 root root      0 May 24 00:37 acme_testing.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root docker 2406 May 24 18:04 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root docker  185 May 23 23:49 .env
```

That's all there is to the configuration.

An `nslookup` outside will give the following:

```
root@server:/opt/traefik# nslookup acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org    canonical name = staging.api.letsencrypt.org.
staging.api.letsencrypt.org     canonical name = 56a5f4b0bc8146689ec3e272c43525f9.pacloudflare.com.
Name:   56a5f4b0bc8146689ec3e272c43525f9.pacloudflare.com
Address: 172.65.46.172
Name:   56a5f4b0bc8146689ec3e272c43525f9.pacloudflare.com
Address: 2606:4700:60:0:f41b:d4fe:4325:6026
```

An `nslookup` INSIDE the container will give the following:

```
manuele@server:/opt$ docker exec -it traefik /bin/sh
/ # nslookup acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Maybe for further information, here is also the log

```
root@server:/opt/traefik# docker-compose up
Recreating traefik ... done
Attaching to traefik
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=info msg="Traefik version 2.2.1 built on 2020-04-29T18:02:09Z"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Static configuration loaded {\"global\":{\"checkNewVersion\":true},\"serversTransport\":{\"maxIdleConnsPerHost\":200},\"entryPoints\":{\"http\":{\"address\":\":80\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{}},\"https\":{\"address\":\":443\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{}}},\"providers\":{\"providersThrottleDuration\":2000000000,\"docker\":{\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"network\":\"traefik_proxy\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15000000000}},\"api\":{\"dashboard\":true},\"log\":{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"format\":\"common\"},\"certificatesResolvers\":{\"le\":{\"acme\":{\"email\":\"<ACME Email>\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"dnsChallenge\":{\"provider\":\"cloudflare\"}}}}}"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/contributing/data-collection/\n"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=info msg="Starting provider aggregator.ProviderAggregator {}"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=https
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.Provider {\"email\":\"<ACME Email>\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"dnsChallenge\":{\"provider\":\"cloudflare\"},\"ResolverName\":\"le\",\"store\":{},\"ChallengeStore\":{}}"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=http
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=info msg="Testing certificate renew..." providerName=le.acme
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"network\":\"traefik_proxy\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15000000000}"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *traefik.Provider {}"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider le.acme: {\"http\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=le.acme
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider internal: {\"http\":{\"services\":{\"api\":{},\"dashboard\":{},\"noop\":{}}},\"tcp\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=internal
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 19.03.9 (API 1.40)" providerName=docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"traefik\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"https\"],\"middlewares\":[\"traefik_auth\"],\"service\":\"api@internal\",\"rule\":\"Host(`<my domain>`)\",\"tls\":{\"certResolver\":\"le\"}},\"traefik0\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"http\"],\"middlewares\":[\"to_https\"],\"service\":\"traefik-traefik\",\"rule\":\"Host(`<my domain>`)\"}},\"services\":{\"traefik-traefik\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.18.0.2:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}}},\"middlewares\":{\"to_https\":{\"redirectScheme\":{\"scheme\":\"https\"}},\"to_https_perm\":{\"redirectScheme\":{\"scheme\":\"https\",\"permanent\":true}},\"traefik_auth\":{\"basicAuth\":{\"users\":[\"<traefik users>\"]}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" serviceName=traefik-traefik entryPointName=http routerName=traefik0@docker middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=http routerName=traefik0@docker serviceName=traefik-traefik
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://172.18.0.2:80" routerName=traefik0@docker serviceName=traefik-traefik serverName=0 entryPointName=http
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware traefik-traefik" middlewareType=TracingForwarder routerName=traefik0@docker entryPointName=http middlewareName=tracing
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=http routerName=traefik0@docker middlewareName=to_https@docker middlewareType=RedirectScheme
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection to https " entryPointName=http routerName=traefik0@docker middlewareName=to_https@docker middlewareType=RedirectScheme
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=http routerName=traefik0@docker middlewareName=to_https@docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Recovery entryPointName=http middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware api@internal" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=https routerName=traefik@docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=BasicAuth routerName=traefik@docker entryPointName=https middlewareName=traefik_auth@docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" routerName=traefik@docker middlewareName=traefik_auth@docker entryPointName=https
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=https middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Try to challenge certificate for domain [<my domain>] found in HostSNI rule" providerName=le.acme rule="Host(`<my domain>`)" routerName=traefik@docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"<my domain>\"]..." providerName=le.acme rule="Host(`<my domain>`)" routerName=traefik@docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Domains [\"<my domain>\"] need ACME certificates generation for domains \"<my domain>\"." providerName=le.acme rule="Host(`<my domain>`)" routerName=traefik@docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:34Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [<my domain>]..." providerName=le.acme rule="Host(`<my domain>`)" routerName=traefik@docker
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:35Z" level=debug msg="Building ACME client..." providerName=le.acme
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:35Z" level=debug msg="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" providerName=le.acme
traefik    | time="2020-05-24T16:05:55Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"<my domain>\": cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp: lookup acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:49272->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout" routerName=traefik@docker providerName=le.acme rule="Host(`<my domain>`)"
```

---

Another option now is to use `docker run ...` instead, so let's try with:

```sh
docker run -it \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    -v /opt/traefik/acme_testing.json:/acme.json \
    -e CF_API_EMAIL="<Cloudflare Email>" \
    -e CF_API_KEY="<Cloudflare API>" \
    -p 80:80 \
    -p 443:443 \
    --network traefik_proxy \
    --name traefik \
    traefik \
    --log.level=DEBUG \
    --api.dashboard=true \
    --providers.docker=true \
    --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false \
    --providers.docker.network=traefik_proxy \
    --entrypoints.http.address=:80 \
    --entrypoints.https.address=:443 \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email="<ACME Email>" \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=acme.json \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.caserver="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge=true \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare
```

Which gives:

```
root@server:/opt/traefik# docker exec -it traefik /bin/sh
/ # nslookup acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Alright try again without networks:

```sh
docker run -it \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    -v /opt/traefik/acme_testing.json:/acme.json \
    -e CF_API_EMAIL="<Cloudflare Email>" \
    -e CF_API_KEY="<Cloudflare API>" \
    -p 80:80 \
    -p 443:443 \
    --name traefik \
    traefik \
    --log.level=DEBUG \
    --api.dashboard=true \
    --providers.docker=true \
    --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false \
    --providers.docker.network=traefik_proxy \
    --entrypoints.http.address=:80 \
    --entrypoints.https.address=:443 \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email="<ACME Email>" \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=acme.json \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.caserver="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge=true \
    --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare
```

Which leads to:

```
root@server:/opt/traefik# docker exec -it traefik /bin/sh
/ # nslookup acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
nslookup: write to '192.168.1.233': Connection refused
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1:53

Non-authoritative answer:
acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org    canonical name = staging.api.letsencrypt.org
staging.api.letsencrypt.org     canonical name = 56a5f4b0bc8146689ec3e272c43525f9.pacloudflare.com
Name:   56a5f4b0bc8146689ec3e272c43525f9.pacloudflare.com
Address: 172.65.46.172

Non-authoritative answer:
acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org    canonical name = staging.api.letsencrypt.org
staging.api.letsencrypt.org     canonical name = 56a5f4b0bc8146689ec3e272c43525f9.pacloudflare.com
Name:   56a5f4b0bc8146689ec3e272c43525f9.pacloudflare.com
Address: 2606:4700:60:0:f41b:d4fe:4325:6026
```

---

Through all of this, the acme files stayed empty, so the problem still persists.

```
root@server:/opt/traefik# ls -Al
total 12
-rw------- 1 root    root       0 May 24 00:37 acme.json
-rw------- 1 root    root       0 May 24 00:37 acme_testing.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root    docker  2406 May 24 18:04 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root    docker   185 May 23 23:49 .env
```

---

If someone can help to fix this, thank you very much in advance.

If you need more information than even all of the stuff I added, feel free to tell me, so I'll provide it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, after hours of tinkering, I found out, that this is a problem that exists somehow across the docker-compose universe. The fix for this is actually pretty simple.

Add the following in each container that needs to talk to the outside world:

```yaml
version: "2"

services:
  <the service>:
    ...
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    ...
```

This will tell the DNS resolver inside the container (which is under 127.0.0.11) to use these domains, instead of whatever is preventing it from talking to the outside world.